# How to fix "Error: Object doesn't support this property or method" javascript error in Internet Explorer?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, popup

On this page with captcha demo:

http://www.tutorialcadet.com/demo/ajaxform/

the captcha image is not refreshing (when clicking on the image) in internet explorer. In firefox. chrome, opera it works fine.

It throws in explorer this popu up error:

```
Line: 155
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

Then when I check the source code in explorer I see this on line 155:

```
<td><div id="captchaimage"><a href="SITE_BASE/register/" id="refreshimg" onclick="refreshimg(); return false;" title="Click to refresh image"><img src="captcha/image.php?1311183335" alt="Captcha image" width="132" height="46" align="left" /></a></div></td>
```

Then when I click on the image again, another error popup shows up:

```
Line: 1
Error: Object doesn't support this property or method
```

When I view the source code I see a ?blank row? on the first row. 
Here is the screen what I mean by blank first row:

http://i54.tinypic.com/23ves1j.jpg

Any suggestion how to solve this? This happens only in internet explorer. I am currently using 9. Is this some kind of internet explorer bug or?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

None of the JS files define the method `refreshimg()`, hence the error.

Also captcha.js already has the code to handle the captcha.

Remove the `refreshimage();` part from the `onclick` of the #refreshimg anchor.

The anchor element should now look like:

```
<a href="SITE_BASE/register/" id="refreshimg" onclick="return false;" title="Click to refresh image">
 <img src="captcha/image.php?1311183335" alt="Captcha image" width="132" height="46" align="left" />
</a>
```

Comment: thanks, there are no errors now, but the image is still not refreshing in explorer. In firefox, chrome and opera I can click as amny times as I want and the image is reloaded, but in explorer the image reload just once (after the first click) and then I can click as many times as I want however image is not refreshed. In firefox, chrome, opera it works fine and refresh on every click.

Comment: @marian: Could be a browser cache issue. Try replacing `$("#captchaimage").load('php/image_req.php');` with `$("#captchaimage").load('php/image_req.php?_o='+ escape(new Date()));`

Comment: Great, you are really a pro. This replacement helps and now it works in explorer too. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Take out `onclick="refreshimg()"`. That function is not defined anywhere and you don't really need that as the click event is already handled in `http://www.tutorialcadet.com/demo/ajaxform/js/captcha.js`

Comment: thanks, there are no errors now, but the image is still not refreshing in explorer. In firefox, chrome and opera I can click as many times as I want and the image is reloaded, but in explorer the image reload just once (after the first click) and then I can click as many times as I want however image is not refreshed. In firefox, chrome, opera it works fine and refresh on every click.